# OL Addin and VMWare

Tags: outlook

We have a managed COM addin for Outlook
works flawlessly on a real  machine
now using VMWare 6.05 I think whe we try and install our addin OL refuses to load us
and we keeo seeing a message( when we go to the manage addins dialog)   saying a runtime error occurred when loading the COM component
Nothing on event viewer

We are seeing this on images of Office 2003 and 2007

anyone ever run into something like this where VMWare images are causing issues with OL addins

Answer (score 0):

Do you have access to the source code of the addin ? if so you could debug or trace the startup. Can you load any other addins? what does the adding do ?
76mel